# Execute preapproval payment with rails & active_paypal_adaptive_payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

How can I execute a preapproved payment using active_paypal_adaptive_payment and rails?
I have pre-approved payment set up (authorised by user) but I don't know how to execute the payment. Should I use execute_payment method? But what params does it take? I cannot find it in the documentation. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The preapproval key needs to be set in the 'Pay' API call (https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation - look for Preapproval Payment section)

Btw can you let me know where you got the active_payPAl_adaptive_payment from ? We can work on getting it updated.

Comment: I think it's this one: https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment

Comment: look in https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal_adaptive_payment.rb - line # 110 - the preapproval_key is where you would pass the preapproval key that has been approved by the user.